# Call to a member function extension() on null when updating my post

Tags: php, laravel, file

Please I have an issue with my code. whenever I want to update my post it always says my files are empty although I have an old file. Please can you help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

This my controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $allowedOptions = Constants::ACTIVE . ",". Constants::INACTIVE;
    $allowedTypes = Constants::MUSIC;
    $data = $request->validate([
        'category_id' => "required|string",
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'content_desccription' => 'required:string',
        "type" => "required|string|in:$allowedTypes",
        "meta_title" => "required|string",
        "meta_keywords" => "required|string",
        "meta_description" => "required|string",
        "is_sponsored" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "is_top_story" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "is_featured" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "is_published" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "can_comment" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
    ]);

    if (!empty([

        $image_path = MediaFilesHelper::saveFromRequest($request->cover_image, "postImages", $request),
        $music_path = MediaFilesHelper::saveFromRequest($request->cover_music, "postMusic", $request),

    ]));
    $data['cover_image'] = $image_path;
    $data['cover_music'] = $music_path;
    $post = Post::where('id', $id)->update($data);
    return redirect()->route('admin.post.index')->with('success_meassage',  'Post updated successfully');

}
```

This is the code handly the file

```
public static function saveFromRequest($file , $path , Request  $request)
{ 
   
   $file_name = Str::slug($request->name, '-').".".$file->extension();
    $file->move(public_path($path) , $file_name);
    return $path."/".$file_name;
  
}
```

Comment: `empty()` can only used on variables.

Comment: public static function saveFromRequest($file , $path , Request  $request)
    { 
       
       $file_name = Str::slug($request->name, '-').".".$file->extension();
        $file->move(public_path($path) , $file_name);
        return $path."/".$file_name;
      
    }

Comment: $file is null as the error says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed your file condition now try I hope it work for you now.

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $allowedOptions = Constants::ACTIVE . ",". Constants::INACTIVE;
    $allowedTypes = Constants::MUSIC;
    $data = $request->validate([
        'category_id' => "required|string",
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'content_desccription' => 'required:string',
        "type" => "required|string|in:$allowedTypes",
        "meta_title" => "required|string",
        "meta_keywords" => "required|string",
        "meta_description" => "required|string",
        "is_sponsored" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "is_top_story" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "is_featured" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "is_published" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
        "can_comment" => "required|string|in:$allowedOptions",
    ]);

     if ($request->file('cover_image')) {
             $image_path = MediaFilesHelper::saveFromRequest($request->cover_image, "postImages", $request);
             $data['cover_image'] = $image_path;
           
        }
        if ($request->file('cover_music')) {
             $music_path = MediaFilesHelper::saveFromRequest($request->cover_music, "postMusic", $request);
             $data['cover_music'] = $music_path;
           
        }
    $post = Post::where('id', $id)->update($data);
    return redirect()->route('admin.post.index')->with('success_meassage',  'Post updated successfully');

}
```